# Help with Regex statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string called 'raw'.  I am trying to parse it in ruby in the following way:

```
raw = "HbA1C ranging 8.0—10.0%"
raw.scan /\d*\.?\d+[ ]*(-+|\342\200\224)[ ]*\d*\.?\d+/
```

The output from the above is `[]`.  I think it should be: `["8.0—10.0"]`.

Does anyone have any insight into what is wrong with the above regex statement?

Note: `\342\200\224` is equal to `—` (em-dash, U+2014).

The piece that is not working is:
`(-+|\342\200\224)`

I think it should be equivalent to saying, match on 1 or more `-` OR match on the string `\342\200\224`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it!

Comment: What happens if the string contains a hyphen instead of an em-dash?  i.e.: "HbA1C ranging 8.0-10.0%"

Answer (score 1):

The original regex works for me (ruby 1.8.7), justs needs the capture to be non-capturing and scan will output the entire match. Or switch to `String#[]` or `String#match` instead of `String#scan` and don't edit the regex.

```
raw = "HbA1C ranging 8.0—10.0%"
raw.scan /\d*\.?\d+[ ]*(?:-+|\342\200\224)[ ]*\d*\.?\d+/
# => ["8.0—10.0"]
```

For testing/building regular expressions in Ruby there's a *fantastic* tool over at http://rubular.com that makes it a lot easier. http://rubular.com/r/b1318BBimb is the edited regex with a few test cases to make sure it works against them.

Answer (score 0):

```
raw = "HbA1C ranging 8.0—10.0%"
raw.scan(/\d+\.\d+.+\d+\.\d+/)
#=> ["8.0\342\200\22410.0"]
```